# When I write search code in php it searches all the data from table

Tags: php

```
$get=$_GET[' search'];

$search="select *from table 1 where keyword like %$get%";
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to mysql injection, you should consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: What is the desired outcome?

Comment: what is that 1 mean?. do you mean LIMIT 1?.

Answer (score 1):

```
$search="select * from table where keyword like '%$get%'";
```

You omitted " `'` ".

Comment: Won't you need to actually build the string? I think `$get` will just be sent plain-text, right?

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans, In sql, string fields require " ' " or " ` ".